# Git/Github Redirecting subdirectories to other repositories

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I keep the sub modules of a project in different repositories.

I host the sub modules in the Modules folder within the main project.

Submodules are ignored in the root project's .gitignore` file.

It's okay, but I want to create links to submodules on github.

I tried using Submodules. However, if I use submodules, I guess the folder contents (`Modules/..`) must be empty.

How can I do that?

**My local workspace:**

```
RootFolder << user/RootFolder
├── .git
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
├── composer.json
└── Modules
    ├── Module1 << user/Module1
    │   ├── .git
    │   ├── README.md
    │   └── composer.json
    └── Module2 << user/Module2
        ├── .git
        ├── README.md
        └── composer.json
```

`RootFolder/.gitignore` content:

```
/Modules
```

It looks like this on Github. (As it's supposed to be)

```
user/RootFolder
├── README.md
└── composer.json
```

However, I want to create links with the same name as the ignored folders:

```
user/RootFolder
├── .gitignore
├── Modules
│   ├── Module1 >> Redirect to https://github.com/user/Module1 (How can I do that?)
│   └── Module2 >> Redirect to https://github.com/user/Module2 (How can I do that?)
├── README.md
└── composer.json
```

Comment: Are you really using submodules here, or do you just have a repository checked out beneath another repository?  Meaning, have you done a `git submodule add ...` in the parent project?  It sounds like you have not - because you should not be `.gitignore`ing the submodules, and if you had used submodules then the experience you would have on GitHub would be as you requested.

Comment: @EdwardThomson But I could not it. I am getting an error while creating submodules because the folders already exist. Can you suggest what I should do without disturbing the current order? All individually repository. The only common point with each other is that they are under the same folder. I am using PhpStorm. I don't want to create a separate project for each repo/module. This is the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert your existing folder structure to use proper submodules:

1. Make sure that both the parent repository and the module repository do not have any changes.  In other words, make sure that `git status` tells you that you have `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.
2. Move the current module repository out of the way, to back it up.  In other words `mv Modules/Module1 Modules/Module1.bak`.
3. Add it as a submodule: `git submodule add -f https://github.com/path_to/module1 Modules/Module1`.  The `-f` is needed since `Modules` still exists in your `.gitignore`.
4. Make sure the file structure is as you like it.  Run a build, test, etc.  Run `git status` to make sure that the `.gitmodules` file and the module itself show up as staged changes.  Commit the changes when you're happy with everything.
5. Repeat starting at step one until you've converted all your submodules.
6. Remove the backup module folders from the `Modules` directory.
7. Remove `/Modules` from your `.gitignore`.

Congratulations(???) you now have submodules.